# Display a fluid width title area with underlying background images

Tags: css

I'm working on a page where I'm looking to create a fluid width title area with underlying images.  The title can be of variable length, but the whole area needs to expand or contract appropriately as the title is longer or shorter.

Here's an example:

[image: Example titles]

I have a sneaking suspicion the answer will have something to do with the z-index property, but haven't really worked with that to date, so I could be wrong.  I'd also like the images to not overlap in the event of a very short title, so min-width may also be necessary.

Can anyone provide an example?

Comment: You should be able to use pseudo elements in CSS or just use multiple background images and position them respectively.

Comment: Here is what I'm talking about: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zuzesome/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks, esswilly, for your quick response!  That's a good start, but I'm looking to have the text actually appear on top of the images at the beginning and end.  I'll admit that I have to use IE8 at work, so that may be causing some trouble (it's also keeping me from being able to get directly to your JSBin example), but it appears the text displays completely within the images instead of overlapping them.  If this isn't the case in more modern browsers, I'll give it another try from home, but I'd like to be certain.

Comment: In that case I would recommend using the multiple backgrounds option. The text will always display on top of the background image and you can adjust the positioning with left and right padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fiddle has a rought example of what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/4fJCL/

```
<span class="left-image"></span>
<span class="text"></span>
<span class="right-image"></span>
```

left and right image should be used to store your images. After that you just need to guarantee that the text is rendered on top by pulling the images under with negative margins. The `position: relative` on the `.text` is to guarantee that it shows over the others.

```
.left-image, .right-image { 
    display:inline-block;
    background: purple;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
}
.text { 
    position: relative;
}

.left-image {
    margin-right: -20px;
}

.right-image {
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: The part I really needed was the negative margin-- I didn't realize this was possible.  Thanks for the heads up!